# How do I make this container stick to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I've made this container with an animation so it comes out from the bottom, but should also stick to the bottom of the page at all times, which it doesn't right now. I've already tried using below, but it doesn't work even if I change the position to fixed. So what am I doing wrong here?

https://jsfiddle.net/TheDeepVoiceGuy/pq1Lc94b/14/

`position: absolute; bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line number `28` doesn't have `;` at the end. And also, you have double semi-colon in the previous (27th) line.

your `.container-fluid` class have some syntax errors:

```
.container-fluid {
    ...
    height: 30%;;
    left: 0%
    ...
}
```

`.container-fluid` class should be like this:

```
.container-fluid {
    background: rgb(133, 173, 143);
    position: absolute;
    height: 30%;
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-animation: expand 1.5s;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: So basically I need to read better, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

### At My End, It Is Working With `position:absolute;bottom:0;`

```css
body {
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgb(128,158,158);
}

/* Header navigation */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html { height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}

.container-fluid {
  background: rgb(133, 173, 143);
  position: absolute;
  height: 30%;;
  left: 0%
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-animation: expand 1.5s;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expand{
  0% {
  margin-top: 27%;
  height: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
}
100% {
  margin-top: 0%;
  height: 30%
}
}

#myDIV {

}


div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.col-left {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-center {
  width: 50%;
  float: inherit;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}

.container-fluid {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col left">
          <div id="myDIV2">
              Default
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col center">
          <div id="myDIV">
            Default text
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

#### Update

Move `bottom:0;` To Just After `position:absolute;` In Your Existing Code, Because `left:0` Doesn't Have A End Semicolon (;) Or Add Semicolon To It -

```
.container-fluid {
  background: rgb(133, 173, 143);
  position: absolute;
  height: 30%;;
  left: 0%
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-animation: expand 1.5s;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

**To ->>**

```
.container-fluid {
  background: rgb(133, 173, 143);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30%;
  left: 0%;
  -webkit-animation: expand 1.5s;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use height and margin to make the animation, you can use only bottom instead.

Here's your updated anmiation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes expand{
  0% {
    bottom: -10%;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```